# return View(model) finds the view but passes a null model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewengine

I am moving the views of an old project from ASPX to Razor, I have almost finished with it without any major issues, but I have come to this kind of problem with some strongly typed views. The thing is that when the controller returns the view using

```
return View(model)
```

the View Egine finds the proper views, always and for all the controller actions, but the model is always null when the View try to access it. But if I use

```
return View (ViewName, model)
```

Everything works like a charm.

So my question is why is the first option working perfectly when the views are using ASPX and not with Razor?

and

Why is it finding the view but passing a null model?

Comment: How are you initializing `model`?

Comment: Well I think that is not the problem, the models contain the proper data when you are in the controller action before returning the view, but once I return the view using  return View(model), it is null in the view

Comment: Can you post the method name for `return View(model)`? It should be the same name of the view unless you specify `[HttpPost, ActionName("ViewName")]`

Comment: For example one action in one of my controller is </br> `public ActionResult Exhibitor( int listingId )` no [HttPost] is the get version of the action. If inside I do `return View(model)` it does find the Exhibitor view but the model is null. If i do `return View("Exhibitor", model)` it works.